# AWS S3: Adding aws:Referer statement breaks ListObjects (403 Forbidden)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to figure out why AWS S3 SDK `ListObjects` stops working (403 Forbidden) when adding an "aws:Referer" statement to my bucket policy.

The following works just fine, until the Referer statement is added to the user policy:

```
<?php
try {
    $result = $this->s3->listObjects([
        'Bucket' => $this->bucket
    ]);

    echo "Keys retrieved!" . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($result['Contents'] as $object) {
        echo $object['Key'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

After adding the statement, the webpage returns a 403 Forbidden as such:

```
Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://myamazonurl.s3.amazonaws.com/?encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `GET https://myBucketName.s3.amazonaws.com/?encoding-type=url` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: AccessDenied
```

This policy works just fine for ListObjects:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetRequestsOriginating",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucketName*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucketName"
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

But as soon as I add an "aws:Referer": block, ListObjects stops working:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allowgetrequestsoriginatingfrom",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucketName*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucketName"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://myLocalSite.vagrant",
                        "http://myLocalSite.vagrant/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is a valid referer header actually being sent with the request?

Comment: @jarmod : Yes, I can verify that a valid referer header is being sent because I can successfully display images from this bucket. I just can't list them. This works:

       `$cmd = $this->s3->getCommand('GetObject', [
            'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
            'Key'    => $this->imageobject
        ]);

        $request = $this->s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, $this->timeout);

        // Get the actual presigned-url
        $presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();

        echo "<img src='$presignedUrl'>";`

Comment: *"I can successfully display images from this bucket. I just can't list them."*  Those are two unrelated things.  The browser is actually fetching the objects, but listing the objects is the SDK, and there's no reason to think the SDK would send a referer header.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot! I am new to the Amazon S3/EC2 world. Would you have any advice for someone wanting to list objects in a bucket while using http referer header to validate the request comes from an approved source URL? Or another technique to display all images in a bucket (I won't know the exact names of the objects to list them manually). Basically I just need to dump all files in a bucket, but only from an approved URL. Thank you!

Comment: Use credentials with the SDK, and remove *everything* but `s3:Get*` from that policy.  The referer header is not a suitable security mechanism for anything but the most trivial hotlinking prevention. This is a limitation of HTTP, not S3.